# How to migrate a 2007 sharepoint list to 2010 with content and save "changed" and "author" data?

Tags: migration, content

For example, I have 2007 sharepoint list with item

Title                 SP list item 
Created         1.1.2007 10:00
Changed        2.1.2007 12:30
Author            Some strange person
Editor             Another strange person

But after migrating I have item

Title            SP list item
Created       31.5.2014 16:00
Changed    31.5.2014 16:00
Author         Me
Editor           Me

I need to save data from fields Created, Changed, Author and Editor after migration. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you origionaly migrate the list with content?

Comment: Using list template and some magic what I have found here: http://tom-dw.blogspot.ru/2010/06/importing-sharepoint-2007-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stsadm.exe -o export
```

that is what you need to use,

in sharepoint 2007 server do:

open up cmd. -> start -> run -> type 'cmd' -> type cd.. untill you get to root directory.

now need to navigate to 12 hive directory:

type 'cd programe files' and hit enter -> type 'cd Common Files' and hit enter -> type 'cd Microsoft Shared' and hit enter -> type 'cd Web Server Extensions' and hit enter -> type 'cd 12' and hit enter ->  type 'cd BIN' and hit enter

you should now have the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN>
```

type:

```
stsadm.exe -o export -url <URL to library> -filename <file name to save it> -includeusersecurity
```

so for you it would be used similar to this:

```
stsadm.exe -o export -url "http://sourceSite/Lists/My List/allitems.aspx" -filename c:/listexport.cab -includeusersecurity
```

above is exporting a list from  `"http://sourceSite/Lists/My List/allitems.aspx"` and saving it as a cab file at c:/listexport.cab, its saving user security that includes created by, edited by ect..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb507233(v=office.12).aspx

move the saved cab file to the 2010 server,

in 2010 server you can now use that saved cab file to import!

```
stsadm.exe -o import -url "http://myNewSite/Lists/My List/allitems.aspx" -filename c:/listexport.cab -includeusersecurity
```

the above is importing the list from c:/listexport.cab to the new site on 2010 `"http://myNewSite/Lists/My List/allitems.aspx"` but it doesnt import workflows!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261866(v=office.12).aspx

or import using powershell:

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity "http://myNewSite/Lists/My List/allitems.aspx" -Path "c:/listexport.cab"-includeusersecurity
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613(v=office.15).aspx